# JAVA ObjUrl.openStream Connection timed out Error

Tags: java, url, network-programming, inputstream

I'm trying to access the contents of a URL using java.net.URL class, but geting following output:

```
Host: java2s.com
Protocol: http
DefaultPort: 80
File: /

ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to sort out this problem.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;



public class URLTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    URL ObjUrl = null;
    InputStream ObjInputStr = null;
    try {
        ObjUrl = new URL("http://java2s.com/");
        System.out.println("Host: " + ObjUrl.getHost());
        System.out.println("Protocol: " + ObjUrl.getProtocol());
        System.out.println("DefaultPort: " + ObjUrl.getDefaultPort());
        System.out.println("File: " + ObjUrl.getFile());

        ObjInputStr =  ObjUrl.openStream();
        int next = -1;

        while ( (next = ObjInputStr.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)next);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine on my system, I doubt about your Internet connection OR the speed!

Comment: @shekharsuman thanks bro, 
 I'm connected to internet through university proxy server. Is that can be reason for this error ?

Comment: You're not using any proxy here. Try setting the system properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` to the appropriate values.